# Lambda ou Linq me traz todos os campo e não somente os da expressão

Tags: c#, linq, rest, asp.net-web-api, expressões-lambda

Apenas para aprendizado mesmo, entender o troço. Eu fiz uma lambda de um banco com apenas 6 campos, assim:

```
 public List<LiberacaoDTO> getAutoriza(int idorcamento)
    {
        var lista = contexto.Liberacoes
       .Where(m => m.IdOrcamento == idorcamento)
       .Select(m => new LiberacaoDTO
       {
           TipoVenda = m.TipoVenda,
           Juros = m.Juros != 0 ? m.Juros : 0,
           Entrada = m.Entrada != 0 ? m.Entrada : 0,
           MaxComi = m.MaxComi,
           Cliente = m.Cliente,
           Filial = m.Filial
       })
       .ToList();

        return lista;
    }
```

Quando o serviço retorna, ele traz todos os campos. Somente os listados na expressão, comtem valor, os demais têm null ou 0. Mas por que todos os campos e não somente os listados na expressão? Abaixo a chamada do meu serviço:

```
public class LiberacaoController : ApiController
    {
        AutorizadorContext contexto = new AutorizadorContext();
        PedidoLiberacao liberacao = new PedidoLiberacao();

        [AcceptVerbs("Get")]
        public IEnumerable<LiberacaoDTO> getLiberacao()
        {
            return liberacao.getAutoriza(1000012093).AsEnumerable().ToList();
         }
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Os campos que você não especificou no .Select são inicializados com o valor default deles. Por exemplo, todos os campos `int` vão ter o valor 0, todos os campos `string` o valor null e todos os campos `DateTime` vão ter o valor 1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM.

Isso acontece porque o .Select cria uma nova instância do objeto `LiberacaoDTO`.

Se você quer que ele retorne apenas os campos do .Select você pode usar um objeto anônimo no .Select:

```
.Select(m => new 
 {
     TipoVenda = m.TipoVenda,
     Juros = m.Juros != 0 ? m.Juros : 0,
     Entrada = m.Entrada != 0 ? m.Entrada : 0,
     MaxComi = m.MaxComi,
     Cliente = m.Cliente,
     Filial = m.Filial
 })
```

O problema dessa abordagem é que você vai perder um pouco da tipagem.

Comment: Entendi Thiago, já fiz assim e tive dificuldade no retorno, mas acho que é porque eu esperava um LiberacaoDTO e por isso deu pau e deixei de lado, pois eu resolvi da forma indicada no post. Vou tentar essa abordagem, retornando um `object`, e ver se pego. Pois isso será consumido em um App Android(Xamarin) e quanto menos dados irrelevantes, melhor, penso eu.

Comment: Se você não precisa desses dados talvez é uma melhor ideia dar uma limpada no seu DTO, ou criar um outro DTO que tenha só o que for preciso. O DTO não precisa ser um reflexo do banco em todos os casos.

Comment: Um DTO pode ter campos de duas ou mais tabelas, para ser usado apenas em uma expressão que necessite desses campos?

Comment: Sim, mas a melhor forma de fazer é criar dois DTOs e um ter uma propriedade que é o outro.

Comment: Tipo receber um ICollection<Outro> do outro? É isso?

Comment: Isso mesmo. Veja minha resposta na sua outra pergunta.